# Insert row to any table with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I want to develop a dynamic insert method with LINQ.

Let's assume I have two tables like:

```
Product
{
   id int,
   name varchar(20),
   price int
}

Factory
{
   id int,
   name varchar(50),
   address varchar(240)
}
```

But, consider that I don't know the tables, but only the names of them.

This is how I get the column names of the table which I know the name of:

```
var db = new DataContext();
var columnNames = db.Mapping.MappingSource
                      .GetModel(typeof(DataContext))
                      .GetMetaType(typeof(table_name))
                      .DataMembers;
```

But I can't figure out how to get the column names of the table which I *don't* know the name of. What I tried so far:

```
context.Mapping.GetTables().FirstOrDefault(
                x=> x.TableName == table_name ).Model.ContextType.Attributes;
```

table_name is dynamically changes and be like: Product, Factory etc.. But this way is a dead end, I think.

So, in the end I couldn't figure out how to get column names of a random table, let alone inserting a row to random table.

I can do this with classic way using `SqlCommand`s but I want to know how to do it with LINQ.

Comment: LINQ to SQL is an object-relational mapper. Are you saying that you want to insert a row, but you don't have an object to represent that row? How are you getting the values that you want to insert into the table?

Comment: Well, if I can get the column names I will create textbox for input, then add the input values according to them.

Comment: I don't think Linq is going to help here. You could write some code in ADO.NET to get the columns definitions from the database, then use some reflection to build an insert/update statement based on the properties of the object that match the columns. I would ask why you need to do this, are you working with some database that is in an unknown state when the app run?

Comment: @jackjop are you trying to build a generic interface for entering information into arbitrary tables? if that is your goal, I like it :)

Comment: Mant101 is right: The whole purpose of an object-relational mapper is to make it easier to work with persisted data by converting it into objects that you can use in the programming language. Since you're not going to program against those objects in this case, you don't get any value from LINQ-to-SQL. You're better off bypassing the ORM and using straight SQL/ADO.NET.

Comment: Use Generic to save/insert data into table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mant101 said in his comment:

> I don't think Linq is going to help here. You could write some code in
>   ADO.NET to get the columns definitions from the database, then use
>   some reflection to build an insert/update statement based on the
>   properties of the object that match the columns. I would ask why you
>   need to do this, are you working with some database that is in an
>   unknown state when the app run?

And as StriplingWarrior gives countenance to him with:

> Mant101 is right: The whole purpose of an object-relational mapper is
>   to make it easier to work with persisted data by converting it into
>   objects that you can use in the programming language. Since you're not
>   going to program against those objects in this case, you don't get any
>   value from LINQ-to-SQL. You're better off bypassing the ORM and using
>   straight SQL/ADO.NET.

Inserting any table using generic methods with LINQ seems impossible.
However, you can do it with SQL.